# Why is my thread getting stuck in Entity Framework SaveChangesAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We have run into a strange issue with Entity Framework. We are attempting to add a new object to the database, and are doing this from a couple different locations. Both are using the following code loaded in through a nuget package:

```
public async Task<Guid> AddRecurrenceHistoryAsync(RecurrenceHistory recurrenceHistory, Guid recurrenceId)
{
    _logger.DebugLogInformation("+");

    try
    {
        using (RecurringPaymentsContext context = new RecurringPaymentsContext())
        {
            var recur = context.RecurringPayments.Single(r => r.Id == recurrenceId);
            if (recur.RecurrenceHistories == null)
            {
                _logger.DebugLogInformation($"No existing histories found");
                recur.RecurrenceHistories = new List<RecurrenceHistory>();
            }
            recur.RecurrenceHistories.Add(recurrenceHistory);
            _logger.DebugLogInformation($"Saving Changes");
            var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            _logger.DebugLogInformation($"Changes Saved result: {result}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.DebugLogError(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }

    _logger.DebugLogInformation(string.Format("- return: {0}", recurrenceHistory.Id));
    return recurrenceHistory.Id;
}
```

Doing this from within our console application works perfectly, however we are also trying to do this from a WebApi service endpoint (simplified test code given below) and when calling it from there the code gets stuck on the `var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();` line.

Web Service Test Endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public HttpResponseMessage Test()
{
    var paymentHistory = new RecurrenceHistory()
    {
        SystemId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        TotalAmount = -1
    };
    _logger.DebugLogInformation("Adding recurrence history");
    paymentHistory.Id = _recurrenceHistoryRepository.AddRecurrenceHistoryAsync(paymentHistory, Guid.Parse("3c412e1b-7a87-e711-910c-0050569b7221")).Result;

    return Request.CreateResponse(true);
}
```

This test endpoint attempts to add the object with a Guid we know is already in the database now just for testing purposes but when run, the code makes it to the above mentioned `var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();` line and then gets stuck. Nothing more is logged and the debugger stops there, never returning. No Exceptions are thrown, however the new row does get added to the database.

tl;dr Summary:

Console app can successfully call this repository method to add the object and can move on, the web service however can successfully add the object to the database but the code never returns from the `context.SaveChangesAsync()` method.

Things we have tried:

Changed the failing line in question to be `await Task.Run(() => context.SaveChangesAsync());`, attempted adding worker processes to the app pool of the service, and a few other things not worth mentioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not call `.Result`, it is a blocking call and, more important, it leads to a deadlock. use `await` instead and have your controller method return a `Task`. This is really the 101 of async/await. See [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for an in depth explanation.

Comment: This was of course how we had it originally written, however we were having issues on the console side when using `await` for some reason and when we switched that to `.Result` it started working. I believe we may have prematurely switched the web service to use `.Result` after that as well and this may have been our problem. I have switched it to use async/await correctly as you said and this step is now working. I will also be revisiting our console app to see if we can make it correctly use await as well. Thanks.

Comment: With C# 7 we will get full async/await support for the main entry point. See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/) that will make it easy to avoid .Result or .Wait in console apps.